# How to only allow alphanumeric using ng-pattern-restrict for first character only?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using https://github.com/AlphaGit/ng-pattern-restrict to restrict input.  What I"m trying to do is only allow alphanumeric for the first character ONLY.  The problem is if I use :

`ng-pattern-restrict="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+"`

it works, but won't allow user to clear the whole string, which I would also like as an option.

Comment: It works in this [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QHgV7m9jlSLPImxcFif2?p=preview).

Comment: I want this restricted to ONLY the first character.

Comment: What do you want to be allowed in characters following the first restricted alphanumeric character?

Comment: How can we use **ng-pattern-restrict** in Angular 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your regex to check for the empty string scenario. Example below:

```
^$|^[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/802qL8JbvaS5djLQKku4?p=preview)

Comment: to only restrict the first character to alphanumeric, you might want regex: `^$|^[A-Za-z0-9].*`

Comment: @plong0 the current regex already does that. You can check it using the plunker example.

Comment: I have successfully input this string "adf@!@$%5756234234!" in your plunker form. No restriction o)

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-pattern-restrict="^([A-Za-z0-9]{0,})$"
```

This will allow only alhpanumeric values.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern allows at least one alphabets and one numeric value but does not allows any special characters.

```
ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/"
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression will help in clearing the input as well not allow any spcial character in the input at any position :   `ng-pattern-restrict="^$|^[A-Za-z0-9]+$"`